# Distribution of python code with a cython library

Tags: python, compilation, cython, compatibility

I want to distribute some python code that uses a cython library that I have written. My question is simple: Must I distribute the source code and setup file and the end user must compile the cython library on their end, or is it possible to distribute the pre-compiled library and expect it to work on the target machine (regardless of differences in operating system and hardware etc)?

Please let me know if the question is not clear and well posed. Thanks!

Comment: Since I am doing a tarball, it sounds like it should be compiled on the target machine in some way.

Comment: Yes - the Cython library will need to be compiled on the target machine (or one that's sufficiently similar... which is surprisingly hard to define). You can distribute the Cython generated ",c" code instead of the ".pyx" code though